# how to get ID without inserting any data into DB

Tags: php, laravel

I wrote a bot. And it scrapes the data and inserting it into DB. When I run the bot first time there is no problem. But when I run the bot second time error pops. Let me explain what I meant.

Here, I am inserting data into DB.

```
if (Menu::where("url", "=", $link."menu")->first()) {
    $insertedMenuId = count($url);
} else {
    $insertedMenuId = Menu::insertGetId($database);
    $this->line("Menu Inserted.");
}
```

Using this `$insertedMenuId` to insert connected data into another table. But the problem here, if I already inserted the data. Then it's not giving me the ID. And `$insertedMenuId` being empty. So second piece of code is not starting. Because there is no id given.

I tried to solve the problem by counting the url. If the url is already inserted. But this time it's giving the wrong id.

Comment: Order the db results by desc and take first item id + 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the record exists, just use its id.

```
$row = Menu::where("url", "=", $link."menu")->first()
if ($row) {
    $insertedMenuId = $row->id;
} else {
    $insertedMenuId = Menu::insertGetId($database);
    $this->line("Menu Inserted.");
}
```